# DHCP and infrastructure

Tags: dhcp

I'm currently deploying domain controllers in my company network, and I would love to have my own DHCP server within my network. The problem is that a another company in the building is controlling the router, which is running a DHCP service. All devices connected to our switch gets an IP from the router in the subnet 192.168.200.x. I have been wondering if theres any feature in Windows Server that would let me do something like:

if DC is ON = then get IP from DC

if DC is OFF = then get IP from Router

[Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZp9s.png)

Comment: If you have another **company**  that has that much control over your network, you should really consider to change your whole network infrastructure.

Comment: Add your own firewall between that router and your switch?

Comment: @StefanR Not firewall, router is needed.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy yes, you are correct. I was thinkin a small firewall appliance, which includes routing functionality etc. like a small mikrotik routerboard.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't. You should think about setting a firewall (or just a router) between your network and the other network. In other words you should become a **new networ**k in the company. Thus you will be separating your network and DHCP wouldn't reach your computers. Then, with the proper configuration, you should not have any problems to use the common services in the building. Although you should have this kind of permission, otherwise you would be setting a rogue DHCP, which means an unauthorized one. I hope this works for you.